# How to start a notebook server in Jupyter Hub using its REST APIs?

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I want to start a notebook server on my Jupyter Hub as described [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/rest-api/index.html#path--users--name--server) and to get started, even the basic command that I am following is not working. I want to make a normal request using my token as mentioned [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/rest-api/index.html#path--users--name--server). 
My code is:

```
import requests
token = "aa36d53a8cb5473a9e7ee07b1f3d8a49"
api_url = 'http://<some_no>.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/hub/api'
r = requests.get(api_url + '/users', headers={ 'Authorization': 'token %s' % token, } )
r.raise_for_status()
```

I, then, face an error, traceback of which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://<some_no>.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/hub/api/users
```

Note: I have generated the token as described in the [official doc](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/docs/source/reference/rest.md#create-an-api-token). I also added the same in my config.yaml file that Jupyter Hub states every now and then.

I am unable to figure out the correct way in such ill-mannered documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with your instance firewall configuration? Do you enable HTTP/HTTPS traffic?

To check if api is working, you can use endpoint which dont need authentication: `http://<some-ip>/hup/api` it should return the JupyterHub version.